# Fluid mesh is invisible

Tags: fluid-simulation

In Blender 3.0.1, my fluid simulation works as expected in all respects except that the mesh is invisible in all preview modes.

In the domain object I have mesh turned on, and in Particle Settings I have Render As set to Object and Viewport Display set to Display As Rendered.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: material settings]
[image: domain settings]
[image: particle render settings]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

result:

[image]

i gave this material to domain + inflow:

[image]

and these settings:

[image]

blend file:

[image]

be careful - i changed a few settings in your blend file. you should not keep on working with it - i had to change some things to see something like cache path, camera ...etc.

Comment: Chris! Thanks so much! It has to be the material that caused it, right? I kept all my domain settings the same and it still worked. Object rather than Halo.

Comment: You are welcome. Just changing the material didn’t work for me. But if it helped you, I am glad 

Answer (score 0):

If you have particles like "bubbles" turned on, make sure you have *Show Emitter* ticked on that Particle System (at least in the render tab)

The emitter for those particles is the mesh. So if you hide the emitter, it hides the base liquid as well.